# Render multiple quersets in html page in Django

Tags: python, html, django, view, django-queryset

views.py

```
def f_page(request, slug, f_slug):
  f = get_object_or_404(F, slug= f_slug)
  if f:
     events = f.event_set.order_by('-pub_date')
     if events:
       for event in events:
       comments = event.comment_set.order_by('-pub_date')
  variables = RequestContext(request, {
     'f' : f,
     'events' : events,
     'comments' : comments,
  })
  return render_to_response('f_page.html', variables)
```

Here events and comments are iterables. Each f has multiple events and then each event has multiple comments. The problem is how do I render this in my html page.I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
{% for event in events %}
    <a href="/{{ event.author.username }}/">{{ event.author.first_name }}</a>
    {{ event.pub_date }}
    {{ event.description }}
    {% for comment in comments %}
        {{ comment }}
        {{ comment.author.first_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The events part shows up right but the comment set doesn't show up.
My models work just fine I have tried everything in the admin panel. I can see where I'm messing it up but am unable to solve it. In 'views.py' the comments object for each event is not being saved. But, I don't know how to resolve it.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `comments` to template you can get it in template.

```
{% for event in events %}
    <a href="/{{ event.author.username }}/">{{ event.author.first_name }}</a>
    {{ event.pub_date }}
    {{ event.description }}
    {% for comment in event.comment_set.all %}
        {{ comment }}
        {{ comment.author.first_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Add [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/options/#ordering) field in your models `Meta` class so that `event.comment_set.all` gives you data in your order.

```
class Comment(Model):
   ...
   class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

Comment: Thanks! It works right. Does making queries in the template have any performance issue?

Comment: @Monica, Don't think there is performance issue. Also, a problem with your code is you want list of `comments` for each event, but you are storing only one (last one).